Can't understand why copy constructor gets invoked
The following should be a MRE:
#include <iostream>

class Vector {
public:
    double x, y, z;

    // Default constructor
    Vector() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {
        std::cout << "Default constructing Vector: (" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    // Constructor with parameters
    Vector(const double x, const double y, const double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {
        std::cout << "Constructing Vector with: (" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Vector() {}

    // Copy constructor
    Vector(const Vector &other) : x(other.x), y(other.y), z(other.z) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructing Vector: (" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    // Assignment operator
    Vector& operator=(const Vector &other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            x = other.x;
            y = other.y;
            z = other.z;
        }
        std::cout << "Assigning Vector: (" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Particle {
public:
    Vector position, velocity, acceleration, appliedForces;
    double damping, inverseMass;

    // Destructor
    ~Particle();

    // Copy constructor
    Particle(const Particle &other);

    // Assignment operator
    Particle& operator=(const Particle &other);

    // Constructor
    Particle(const Vector &p, const Vector &v, const Vector &a, const Vector &f, double d, double m)
        : position(p), velocity(v), acceleration(a), appliedForces(f), damping(d), inverseMass(m == 0 ? 0 : 1.0 / m) {
        std::cout << "Constructing Particle with position: " << position.x << ", " << position.y << ", " << position.z << std::endl;
    }
};

Particle::~Particle() {
    // Implementazione del distruttore
}

void test2() {
    Vector p1_p(5, 0, 0);
    Vector p1_v(1, 2, 0);
    Vector p1_a;
    Vector p1_f;
    double p1_d = 0;
    double p1_m = 1;

    std::cout << "Before Particle" << std::endl;
    Particle p1(p1_p, p1_v, p1_a, p1_f, p1_d, p1_m);

    std::cout << "Particle 1 initial position is: (" << p1.position.x << ", " << p1.position.y << ", " << p1.position.z << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Launching" << std::endl;
    test2();
    std::cout << "Terminating" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Finally, the console output. Since a copy constructor for each vector declared at the beginning of test2 gets invoked at the exact time the Particle constructor is called, what's happening? Isn't that not supposed to happen since I'm passing Vectors as const references?

Launching
Constructing Vector with: (5, 0, 0)
Constructing Vector with: (1, 2, 0)
Default constructing Vector: (0, 0, 0)
Default constructing Vector: (0, 0, 0)
Before Particle
Copy constructing Vector: (5, 0, 0)
Copy constructing Vector: (1, 2, 0)
Copy constructing Vector: (0, 0, 0)
Copy constructing Vector: (0, 0, 0)
Constructing Particle with position: (5, 0, 0)
Particle 1 initial position is: (5, 0, 0)
Terminating

I don't understand why copy constructors are called. I made sure to pass every Vector as const references.

position(p) etc. - assuming position and the rest of the Vectors members are not references - a copy is done when initializing them. As mentioned above a [mre] will clarify it.

... and while making them reference members may solve the immediate problem, that usually ends up being hard to work with.

I did not have any "Copy constructing Vector" in my output.  I suspect you have a bug in the code not provided.  (Or my implementation of the missing pieces did not recreate the bug in your code which would have avoided copies.)

@OP You should be printing the value of this in your constructor and assignment operators, not just a simple message.  If you had printed this, you would have a better idea of what is happening.  Second, if you had used a debugger and put a breakpoint in the constructor, you would then simply look at the call stack to see what function(s) were being called to hit the breakpoint.  Last, if you forgot to print a message (including this) in your destructors.  Basically this boils down to not putting in the appropriate debugging output to see what is going on.

@lucottoDA "I should have managed to edit the post to provide a MRE" - Indeed you did! Good work. One of the few questions that actually gets reopened!

@lucottoDA In your constructors and assignment operators, just simply add << " " << this to those cout statements.  Then add into the destructors a simple "destruction" message, along with << " " << this.  Then you will actually get the address of the objects being created, copied, and destroyed.  Your current ouput shows none of this information.  What you have now is relying on x,y,z to give you all of your information -- clearly you cannot just use those items -- you also need the object's instance pointer to clearly see what is going on.

Side note: Particle::~Particle() {     // Implementazione del distruttore } - If all you have is a destructor that does nothing, then you should either leave it out entirely or =default it - that way your class may still be trivial (or at least it will have a trivial destructor).

In the mem-initializer list of this constructor
Particle::Particle(const Vector &p, const Vector &v, const Vector &a, const Vector &f, double d, double m)
    : position(p), velocity(v), acceleration(a), appliedForces(f), damping(d), inverseMass(m) {
    std::cout << "Constructing Particle with position: " << position << std::endl;
}

there are explicitly called the copy constructor of the class Vector as for example
position(p)

As for your statement

I don't understand why copy constructors are called. I made sure to
pass every Vector as const references.

then it seems you think that if you passed arguments by reference and not by value then the copy constructor for arguments will not be called. However the copy constructor is called to create members of the class Particle by means of objects of the same type (through references to them) used as arguments.
